# Charge Distribution on a Microstrip Line

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, charge, microwave, microstrip

let's consider a microstrip line connected to a voltage source V0 (applied between the strip and GND plane). According to foundation for microwave engineering (collin) book, the surface charge density on the strip is the following one:

[image]

[image]

I am looking for a **physical explanation** of this behaviour.

Precisely, let's consider the instant in which the microstrip line is connected to the voltage generator. Step by step:

1) The voltage source provides many positive charges at its positive terminal and many negative charges at its negative terminal. Let's focus on the first one, which is directly connected to the strip.

2) Charges provided by the voltage source will try to distance themselves due to Coulomb repulsion and will go predominantly at the edges of the strip (this may explain the reason by which the surface density is infinite at the edges of the graph).

3) The voltage source will provide other charges which I think will go at the center of the strip. How will the charge distribution be influenced by this factor?

4) Where will the following charges locate?

Comment: What are the axes of the graph in your question precisely?

Comment: The y axis is the surface charge density, the x axis is the position on the strip width